# Is my audio jack broken or do I have a bad splitter?

Tags: laptop, audio

All my earphones only play through the left side on my laptop until I have the jack half-way plugged in, in which it plays both sides just fine.

I bought a headset with a mic and it came with a splitter and it only plays through the left side but if I half-way plug in the headset jack with the splitter it will play through both left and right but the mic will not work.

If my jack is broken, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

> All my earphones only play through the left side on my laptop until I
> have the jack half-way plugged in, in which it plays both sides just
> fine
>
> .. headset with a mic and it came with a splitter and it only plays
> through the left side but if I half-way plug in the headset jack with
> the splitter it will play through both left and right but the mic will
> not work.

You really have the same issue with / without the new headset.

You need to replace the audio jack and should let a local repair shop do this as they will have the skills and tools to do the job.

Good luck.